# PHP: calling a child tag simplexml

Tags: php, xml, parsing

Trying to parse a YouTube feed using PHP

```
simplexml_load_file();
```

I am able to access other tags pretty simply using

```
$xml->id;
```

When I try to access

`<openSearch:totalResults>`

with

`$xml->openSearch->totalResults;`

I don't get any results

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`openSearch` is a namespace - it's not the name of the tag, or a parent, or anything like that. Somewhere in the document there will be an attribute called `xmlns:openSearch` which defines the openSearch namespace (with an URL).

You can use the `children` method to get children of a certain namespace, and do something like:

```
$xml->children('openSearch', true)->totalResults
```

(You can also use the full URL for the namespace instead of 'openSearch' and leave the `true` off of the end, which may be beneficial if they ever change their markup or you parse similar feeds from elsewhere which use a different namespace prefix)

Answer (score 0):

Those elements are in a different XML namespace, to obtain them you need to do:

```
$xml->children('openSearch', true);
```

Then in the collection that is returned, you will find the elements you need.